# Adding additional logic to Java Collection

Tags: java, collections

I have 3 different TreeSet objects in my application, all of which store the same class of object.

However, at any one point of time, a single object may exist in only one of the TreeSets.

So, if I queried each TreeSet using contains() for a particular object it should exist in only one of them.

Is there an easy way to add this kind of logic to my TreeSet easily? Obviously I can perform the above contains() check myself after each operation but just wondering if there are better ways?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can keep a map that maps objects to the TreeSet to which they currently belong. If an object has no entry, it can be added to a TreeSet; otherwise it must be removed from the mapped TreeSet before it assigned to a new one.

EDIT:

Per your request, here's a code snippet for how this might be done:

```
Map<MyObject, TreeSet<MyObject>> map = new HashMap<MyObject, TreeSet<MyObject>>();

void addToSet(MyObject obj, TreeSet<MyObject> set) {
    TreeSet<MyObject> otherSet = map.get(obj);
    if (otherSet != null) {
        otherSet.remove(obj);
    }
    set.add(obj);
    map.put(obj, set);
}

void removeFromSet(MyObject obj, TreeSet<MyObject> set) {
    set.remove(obj);
    map.remove(obj);
}
```

Comment: Not sure I follow, do you have a little code snippet or algorithm for reference?

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like:

```
import java.util.*;
class Sets {
    Sets(TreeSet<Integer> set1, TreeSet<Integer> set2, TreeSet<Integer> set3) {
        this.set1 = set1;
        this.set2 = set2;
        this.set3 = set3;
    }
    boolean add(TreeSet<Integer> set, Integer i) {
        if (set == set1) {
            if (set2.contains(i)) {
                set2.remove(i);
                return set.add(i);
            } else if (set3.contains(i)) {
                set3.remove(i);
                return set.add(i);
            } else return set.add(i);
        }
        else if (set == set2) {
            if (set1.contains(i)) {
                set1.remove(i);
                return set.add(i);
            } else if (set3.contains(i)) {
                set3.remove(i);
                return set.add(i);
            } else return set.add(i);
        }
        else if (set == set3) {
            if (set1.contains(i)) {
                set1.remove(i);
                return set.add(i);
            } else if (set2.contains(i)) {
                set2.remove(i);
                return set.add(i);
            } else return set.add(i);
        }
        return false;
    }
    final TreeSet<Integer> set1, set2, set3;
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<Integer> set1 = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        set1.add(1);
        TreeSet<Integer> set2 = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        set2.add(2);
        TreeSet<Integer> set3 = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        Sets sets = new Sets(set1, set2, set3);
        System.out.println(set1);
        System.out.println(set2);
        System.out.println(set3);
        sets.add(set3,1);
        sets.add(set3,2);
        sets.add(set3,3);
        System.out.println(set1);
        System.out.println(set2);
        System.out.println(set3);
    }
}
```